# Apply lm() over matrix for 1 variable in R

Tags: r, loops, apply

I am trying to use the apply() family of functions to regress each column of a matrix on a vector to generate a set of coefficients for each column, but I can't wrap my head around it. For example, I can do this with a loop as follows:

```
x <-  matrix(runif(10*10), 10,10)
y <-  runif(10)

coefs <- matrix(NA, ncol = 2, nrow = 10)

for(i in 1:10){
    coefs[i,] <- lm(y~x[,i])$coef
}
```

Help in translating the loop above to an apply function would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
t(apply(x, 2, function(x.col) lm(y~x.col)$coef))
```

We apply over your matrix `x`, by column (this is what the `2` means), and we define a simple function to get the results.  `apply` will stack the results automatically into a 2 row matrix, which we convert into the desired format with `t`:

```
      (Intercept)        x.col
 [1,]   0.6314854 -0.567179167
 [2,]   0.3679481  0.020019158
 [3,]   0.2448379  0.280314036
 [4,]   0.4195727 -0.082207564
 [5,]   0.1249273  0.425974675
 [6,]   0.4567553 -0.194174789
 [7,]   0.2653036  0.181709766
 [8,]   0.2963443  0.217408463
 [9,]   0.2902572  0.174962624
[10,]   0.3730373  0.007380176
```

Note there is nothing wrong with your loop.  Since you initialize `coefs`, it should be just as fast as `apply`.  If you're going for speed you should look at a faster option for calculating slope and intercept than `lm` as that does a whole bunch of other things as well that slow it down.